# Java jvm.dll цена

Tags: java, dll

Являются ли компоненты для языка программрования *java* платными в корпоративных масштабах?

В частности интересует цена библиотеки **jvm.dll**.

Comment: как я знаю java посностью бесплатная. А откуда инфа что нужно за java платить?

Comment: Не нашел данных по этой либре с точным описанием платная она или нет, вот и решил узнать.

Comment: по http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?jvm ссылки, утилита для этой библиотека платная -  Premium стоит 30$. Но сама библиотека думаю нет

Comment: @Saidolim, на этом сайте все "утилиты" платные. Кажется мне, что это просто развод ;)

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/products/index.html

Comment: @LEQADA мне тоже так кажется. столько знаю java но не видел что бы она была платной

Answer (score 2):

Язык есть язык - **бесплатно**, виртуальная машина распространяется тоже **бесплатно** (jvm). Сторонние библиотеки, классы и тд могут быть платными.